# Display content of RibbonTab depending on current context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, ribbon

I have read a lot about wpf and mvvm the last days; on SO and other websites. My program will have a Ribbon menu. At program start, a limited menu shall be seen. When the project data is loaded, the menu changes to full menu. And depending on the RibbonTab the content changes.

I found a good example by Barry Lapthorn ([MVVMLight Using two views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views)). But I am not clear about how to make the ribbon menu depend on the content (small menu at start; full menu when the project is loaded).

It would be great if someone can help me with this - either with ideas, an example, etc. :)

Comment: Basically, what you would do is expose some kind of view state property (for two possible states, it could be just a boolean `ShowFullMenu`) on the view model, and then you have a trigger in the XAML that shows one of the two menus depending on the value of that property.

Comment: "Either a link to a thread " <<< asking for external resources  is discouraged on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you Tseng. I changed the text.

Answer (score 0):

Create two menus for either situation.

Use a variable to keep track of content change.

Then switch Menus using `DataTrigger`.